# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't start on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have used IDEA for several months, and it was ok until now.

Now launching IDEA from shortcut has no effect.
I suppose that happened after some updates.

I tried to reinstall IDEA, but problem is still there.
Launching idea.sh from Terminal gives similar effect:

```
chronoexp@ChronoExp-PC:~/Programs/idea-IC-135.1289/bin$ ./idea.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
chronoexp@ChronoExp-PC:~/Programs/idea-IC-135.1289/bin$
```

Note that message about HotSpot Server is ok. Previously after printing that, IDEA was launched. Now it simply kicks out with no error message.

Maybe there are some log files, where I can see possible error?

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>   IDEA Version: 13.1.5 Build: 135.1289
>   java version "1.8.0_20"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: Is there any output in Idea log (you can find it at `~/.IdeaIC13/system/log/idea.log`)?

Comment: @zvdh there is no "log" folder in ~/.IdeaIC13/system

Comment: According to [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) log should be exactly there, otherwise check **idea.log.path** property in `IDEA_home/bin/idea.properties` file to find out if the default log location path is changed.

Comment: @zvdh path in properties is just like yours. Anyway, rebooting the system solved the problem. Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, restarting Ubuntu solved the problem. So easy!

p.s. It's a shame that I just did not try to reboot the system before asking question...

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo killall java
```

Snap! This worked for me

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for providing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how the command solves the issue?

Comment: I've got the experiMENTAL version from snap. This is working like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ (and few other Java programs) sometimes has a problem with window not appearing or being frozen. It took me some time to find this simple solution that might be useful for someone in the future:

`wmname LG3D`

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: This one didn't work for me. What worked was `sudo killall java`. Then reopen idea.

Comment: @AFP_555 but this solution could probably cause other issues to the system if there exist any other software depending on the JAVA. so this is not the optimal solution.
Maybe there other solutions to this IntelliJ IDEA software specifically out there.

Answer (score 3):

Find the `pid` by `grep` like

```sh
ps -aux | grep idea
```

and kill all the open instances like `sudo kill 12233(pid)` and boom, you are all set to go.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a five year old question with an accepted answer it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Also formatting commands by surrounding them with backticks makes them more readable than putting them in parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Check that even if it is installed in a subfolder of your home directory, the owner of **idea-IC-135.1289** is you (recursively).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the /bin and run ./idea.sh. This should solve your issue, without restarting Ubuntu.

Comment: in /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/430/bin precisely, or /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/bin

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the JDK in IntelliJ (By Choose Boot Java Runtime) as JDK 11, however my IntelliJ was setup as JDK 17, thus, I had to access my .config file and JetBrains, where you can find idea.jdk (I just changed from 1.11 to 1.17) and it's working again.

Comment: How did you do that?