# Intelli-J won't start - Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot get Intelli-J Community Edition to start on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I keep receiving the error:

*Everything has changed
WARN: Python Community Edition not loaded: until build 181.SNAPSHOT < IC-182.4892.20
Everything has changed*

And I do not know what that means. I have tried everything on the following thread: [IntelliJ IDEA doesn't start on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175371/intellij-idea-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu) without any luck. After I did the following command, that was on the above thread:
    `wmname LG3D` the Intelli-j window shows up, loads, and then disappears. In the top left hand corner, it says that it is running, but nothing happens when I click on either that or the icon on the launcher. No mention of it when I look at the processes running, either, even though it still appears in the corner. Can anyone help me with why this is happening? I can remember a time fairly recently when it wasn't -- I think it might be something related to an update?

Comment: I had a similar issue, running `<ideaFolder>/bin/idea.sh`. It was printing `Everything has changed`. I restarted Ubuntu and it works now.

Comment: Please try to remove python plugin related folder from "plugins" directory: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I uninstalled the current version and deleted everything that I could find from the plugins directory and elsewhere pertaining to IntelliJ settings. (`Ctrl + H` to show hidden folders). Then I reinstalled Intellij with snaps, i.e. `$sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic --edge` for the community version (replace 'community' with 'ultimate' for the ultimate version). That seemed to do the trick. For more information see here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/install-intellij-idea-with-snaps/.